# Redux Framework Warning in wordpress Theme and Theme customization options not working

Tags: wordpress, themes, cdn

Redux Framework Warning ace-editor-js CDN unavailable. Some controls may not render properly. Please wait a few minutes, then try refreshing the page. Unable to load some remotely hosted scripts This error accoured and Theme customization options not working and not display when click on options it will display blank.

[image]

I am begginer in wordpress, Anyone can give the suggestions why this error occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used Redux Framework Plugins Then All options are working.

[image]

I got solution from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redux-framework-warning-cdn-unavailable

Answer (score 0):

The above solution has nothing useful for me.

My solution was to disable the code snippet in my wp-config to restrict external url requests

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true );
  if ( WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL ) {
    define( 'WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', '*.wordpress.org,*.example.com' ); 
  }
```

Alternatively, I could add the CDN domain used by redux into the define...

For me - it resolved my problem.

My next idea would be to check the htaccess for Order Deny,Allow....